# escaping hyphen and quotes in expect script

Tags: linux, expect

Hello I am using expect to automate a login task. 
but the script fails if password starts with a hyphen
How can I escape that

I have a lot of trouble properly escaping ' " or other characters Is there a way I can encode all my characters and send expect the encoded string for it to decode before sending

This is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -o "PubkeyAuthentication no" -l user 10.10.10.10
expect "password: "
send "-cpass\'ok\r"
expect "$ "
```

Comment: Are you trying to escape the single quote or the space here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the man page:

> The -- flag forces the next argument to be interpreted as a string rather than a flag.  Any string can be preceded by "--" whether
>   or not it actually looks
>        like a flag.  This provides a reliable mechanism to specify variable strings without being tripped up by those that accidentally 
>   look  like  flags.   (All
>        strings starting with "-" are reserved for future options.)

Which means you should write your `send` something like:

```
send -- "-cpass\'ok\r"
```

Note: you'll have problems trying to pass any string starting with a hyphen; this won't work: `send "-cpass"`, if your string has a hyphen you need to use `--` flag.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to save your password in a variable:

```
password=-cpass\'ok\r
send "$password"
```

You simply write a `\` in front of every `'`,`"` or spaces.

Comment: Tcl/Expect does not support the `var=value` syntax.